# Proving a sequence with infinitely many zeros is not zero heavy?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Is my counterexample correct?

> If a sequence contains an infinite number of zeroes, is it necessarily
>   zero-heavy? If not, provide a counterexample.

*Solution*. Consider the sequence $(a_n)$ defined such that $a_n = 0$ whenever $n = 2^k$ for some $k\in\mathbf{N}$ and is $1$ otherwise, then given any $M\in\mathbf{N}$ we may choose a $k\in\mathbf{N}$ such that $2^{k+1}-(2^{k}+1)>M$ then given the construction of the sequence if $n\in\{2^{k}+1,2^{k+1}+2,\dots,(2^{k}+1)+M\}$ we have $a_n\neq 0$.The sequence in question then cannot possibly be zero heavy.

**NOTE:** We define a sequence to be zero heavy if $$\exists M\in\mathbf{N}\forall N\in\mathbf{N}\exists n\in\{N,N+1,\dots,N+M\}(x_n=0)$$

Comment: Your construction works.

Comment: It's correct. Another example: Let $a_n=0$ if $n$ is prime and $a_n=1$ otherwise. If $2\leq  K>M$ then  $\{K!+j:2\leq j\leq K\}$  contains no primes because  $K!+j >j>1$ and $ j$ divides $K!+j$ (... when $K\geq j >1).$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks good! The only part I might do/phrase at all differently is:

> ...we may choose $k\in\mathbf{N}$ such that $k>\log_2(M+1),$ so that $2^{k+1}-(2^k+1)>M,$ and so, given the construction of the sequence, if....